# Factory for CRTP based classes

Tags: c++, factory, crtp

I'm using CRTP for a set of classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T, class Derived>
struct signal
{
    T t;   // Used elsewhere in the code...

    static std::string name() {
        return Derived::name_sub();
    }

private:
    signal() = default;
    friend Derived;
};

struct signal_boolean : signal<bool, signal_boolean>
{
    static std::string name_sub() {
        return "boolean";
    }
};

struct signal_integer : signal<int, signal_integer>
{
    static std::string name_sub() {
        return "integer";
    }
};

int main() {
    signal_boolean sb;
    signal_integer si;
    std::cout << sb.name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << si.name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So far everything is fine.
Now I want to extend the `signal` class with a serialization interface. For this question, it doesn't matter how the serialization looks like. We assume that there's a `container` provided by the serializer for (de)serialization of a class:

```
// Serialization container
class container;

template<typename T, class Derived>
struct signal
{
    static std::string name() {
        return Derived::name_sub();
    }

    container to_container() const {
        container c;

        c.add_string("name", name());

        return c;
    }

private:
    signal() = default;
    friend Derived;
};
```

So far everything is still okay. I can call `signal_boolean::to_container()` to serialize a `signal_boolean` object.

But from here on things are a bit more tricky: For deserialization I need a factory that accepts a `container` and returns an object of the appropriate derived `signal` class.

I came across [this gem](http://www.nirfriedman.com/2018/04/29/unforgettable-factory/) which taught me how to create a nice registerable factory.
However, I can't figure out how I properly need to adapt this into my code for handling my `signal` classes.

I started by creating the `signal_factory` class which implements the registerable factory pattern:

```
    static std::string demangle(const char* name) {
        int status;
        std::unique_ptr<char, void (*)(void *)> res{
            abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status), std::free};
        return (status == 0) ? res.get() : name;
    }

    template <class base, class ...Args>
    class factory
    {
    public:
        template <class ...T>
        static std::unique_ptr<base> make(const std::string &s, T&&... args) {
            return data().at(s)(std::forward<T>(args)...);
        }

        template <class T>
        struct registrar : base
        {
            friend T;

            static bool registerT() {
                const auto name = demangle(typeid(T).name());
                factory::data()[name] = [](Args... args) -> std::unique_ptr<base> {
                    return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                };
                return true;
            }
            static bool registered;

        private:
            registrar() : base(key{}) {
                (void)registered;
            }
        };

        friend base;

    private:
        class key
        {
            key() {};

            template<class T>
            friend struct registrar;
        };

        using func_type = std::unique_ptr<base> (*)(Args...);

        factory() = default;

        static auto& data() {
            static std::unordered_map<std::string, func_type> s;
            return s;
        }
    };

    template <class base, class ...Args>
    template <class T>
    bool factory<base, Args...>::registrar<T>::registered = factory<base, Args...>::registrar<T>::registerT();
```

But now I'm stuck. I would make the `signal` class inherit from `factory::registrar` as shown in the example of the website linked above. However, my base class (in their example the `Animal` class) is a class template.

How can I make this work? Do I need to extend the `factory::registrar` struct template to accept template template parameters? I tried to do this but I got quickly lost in the template syntax.

Is this even the right approach? I want a way to create a `signal` derived class object based on the information I get during runtime from the deserialization `container`.